# VAT Validation using EU VIES service not working

Tags: magento-1.7, soap, vat

The VAT validation on our Magento 1 install stopped working. Annoying, because we have quite a few foreign customers who like the fact that they do not have to pay VAT on our site.
The feature worked for years, but stopped working.

In the system.log I see message like this:
ERR (3): Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient(http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/services/checkVatService?wsdl): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known  in /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Helper/Data.php on line 619
2020-12-02T21:23:30+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/services/checkVatService?wsdl"  in /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Helper/Data.php on line 619

Answer (score 0):

I checked the URL in the system log, but that was returning a 302 to a different URL:
Location: http://taxudp92.cc.cec.eu.int:7174/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl

When I checked that location, the server could not be found.

With some googling, I was lucky and found the correct URL for the soap asdl file:
https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl

I replace the old URL with the new URL in file:
/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Helper/Data/php around line 75.
(I know this is not the correct place as you should not alter the original system files, but for me this worked). I probable have to do this again after installing upgrades. That is why I am documenting on magento.stackexchange...